# Delete Random Characters From String

Tags: java, string, random

This is a project for school. The objective is to create a program that reads a user's input, then shortens that input by randomly deleting characters until it reaches 140 characters. Here's what I have done so far. Currently, it's deleting only one character and then stops running. Thanks for any advice

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the tweet you want to shorten:");
        String tweet = null;

        tweet = keyboard.nextLine();

        int tweetLength = tweet.length();

        Random rand = new Random();


        do {

        } while (tweetLength <= 140); {
            int characterposition = rand.nextInt(tweetLength);
            String shorttweet = tweet.substring(0, characterposition-1);
            String shorttweet2 = tweet.substring(characterposition);

            tweet = shorttweet + shorttweet2;
            System.out.println("Shortented Tweet: " + tweet);
            tweetLength = tweet.length();

        }
```

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive loop...

Answer (score 1):

The format of your loop is wrong. You should use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the tweet you want to shorten:");
    String tweet = null;

    tweet = keyboard.nextLine();

    int tweetLength = tweet.length();

    Random rand = new Random();

    while (tweetLength > 140) {
        int characterposition = rand.nextInt(tweetLength);
        String shorttweet = tweet.substring(0, characterposition);
        String shorttweet2 = tweet.substring(characterposition + 1);

        tweet = shorttweet + shorttweet2;
        System.out.println("Shortented Tweet: " + tweet);
        tweetLength = tweet.length();
    }
```

What you had before was an empty `do-while` loop followed by one block of code, which was why it was only happening once. Note that I also changed the loop condition - we should loop while the length is greater than 140, not while it is less than.

For learning purposes, below is your original loop:

```
do {
    //you didn't do anything inside the loop!
} while (tweetLength <= 140);

//all of your code was after the loop
```

Edit:

We also needed to fix this line `rand.nextInt(tweetLength)` because that will return an `int` between 0 (inclusive) and `tweetLength` (exclusive). When this returns 0 the next line will break because you are calling `substring(0, -1)`. Thanks to PatrickParker for this point

Comment: your position is off by one. this can result in java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when nextInt returns 0.

Comment: no, you just made it impossible to remove the first character.

Comment: @PatrickParker No, when characterposition is 1, its lowest value, shorttweet will be an empty string and shorttweet2 will be everything after the first character. the first character is removed fine in this case.

Comment: you do realize that the first character of any java String is at position 0 right?

Comment: @PatrickParker of course. please explain exactly how that causes an issue in this case.

Comment: @PatrickParker The lowest value that can be returned by `nextInt` is 0. I add 1 to that, so the lowest value that can be stored in `characterposition` is 1. Then from OP's code he calls `substring(0, characterposition-1) + substring(characterposition)`, which will be evaluate to `substring(0,0) + substring(1)` which strips the first character. If my logic is wrong, please point out how.

Comment: Ok, so the name of the variable is a bit deceptive now. it's positionafter. which means it is impossible to remove the last character now.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better replace the `String` by a `StringBuilder`, which is much faster for this kind of operations:

```
private static String shorten(String str, int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (sb.length() > length) {
        int pos = rand.nextInt(sb.length());
        // The deleteCharAt() method deletes the char at the given
        // position, so we can directly use the retrieved value
        // from nextInt() as the argument to deleteCharAt().
        sb.deleteCharAt(pos);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

To answer your question:

You are using a do-while loop, which has this format:

```
do {
    // Things to do
} while (condition);
```

Your block behind this piece of code has nothing to do with this loop. It's just an **anonymous code block**:

```
{
    // Statements
}
```

So first your empty `do-while` loop executes, and then the code below it — once, of course.

You should use a `while` loop instead:

```
while (lengthOfString > 140) {
    // remove a character
}
```